# (WiX) Write product info to registry for dual purpose installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm making a dual purpose package in WiX according to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx).

So I initialized the ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER according to the article:

```
<Property Id='ALLUSERS' Value='2' />
<Property Id='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' />
```

In my dialog I set MSIINSTALLPERUSER="1" if the user selected the per-user option. For per-machine I set MSIINSTALLPERUSER="".

So far so good. The problem is that my product info gets written to HKEY_CURRENT_USER all the time. Unless I initialize MSIINSTALLPERUSER with an empty string. But I that would require administrator permissions even for a per-user installation

How do I write the product info to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if the user chose the per-machine installation?

Edit: Cleaned up question.

Comment: Is ALLUSER set to 2?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes. I initialized the installer with ALLUSERS="2" and MSIINSTALLPERUSER="1" (as described in the article from Microsoft)

Comment: Assuming that "product information" means, the Program/Features stuff, then it looks like you're still in per user mode, and I'd recommend getting a full verbose log to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the installer uses HKLM, when I set MSIINSTALLPERUSER="" from the command line. So I compared the verbose logs of my installer initialized with MSIINSTALLPERUSER="" and MSIINSTALLPERUSER="1" and found out, that it sets ALLUSERS="1" if MSIINSTALLPERUSER was null.

So I simply added the following line for the per-machine option in the dialog:

```
<Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1">1</Publish>
```

I expected that if ALLUSERS is 2, it would check the MSIINSTALLPERUSER property to determine the registry location, but that was obviously wrong. Unfortunately it's not mentioned in the article that you have to set ALLUSERS to 1 too and that MSIINSTALLPERUSER alone is not enough.